# mailto link not working within a frame chrome (over https)

Tags: html, google-chrome, mailto

I have a mailto link on a page. It works as expected when the page is loaded by itself.

However when the page is loaded via a frameset in Chrome nothing happens. With the developer tools loaded the error `"[blocked] The page at https://mysite.com ran insecure content from mailto:..."` is displayed.

How can I fix/workaround this?

Comment: It looks like Dale has filed a bug with Chrome: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=306349&q=mailto%20gmail&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Week%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified

Comment: `tel:` links are affected too. Same solutions apply.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I also had this issue recently with an iframe.  Using the top frame worked and should be compatible with all major browsers.

```
window.top.location = 'mailto:...';
```

Comment: So you would have to write a javascript onclick (or something similar) to handle this mailto: link?

I'm just looking for a the syntax for this solution.

Comment: Yes, using "top" is the trick, but you can do it with HTML alone!

    <a target="_top" href="mailto:...">email</a>

Comment: Hi, I just came across this issue today.. and this solution works. however I just want to understand why it works? why setting the target to `_top` works? Does the browser not care to check for security if an anchor link is outside of an iFrame?

Comment: tried all combinations, this is the only one that worked for me in Chrome without having to open a blank window

Comment: @kendsnyder I am using a component that accepts an onClick, for me this is the only thing that worked. I can't use HTML for this one, i.e. it needs to be triggered programmatically through callback.

Answer (score 33):

Yes, using "top" is the trick, but you can do it with HTML alone!

```
<a target="_top" href="mailto:...">email</a>
```

Comment: This is excellent. It allows mailto links to now work within an iframe using the Chrome browser. Thank you very much!!!

Comment: I had a problem making `mailto:` links in a Facebook frame. This worked!

Comment: Never knew what "_top" was for, until now (shame on me). This solves some problems I had on a range of Android phones as well. Thanks!

Comment: Also fixes `mailto:` links when using URL Frame masking to forward a URL!

Comment: I would recommend using _blank instead of _top. If the user set a web-based email client as the default email tool, the email client page will replace the parent page with _top.

Comment: @Adamy, Yes the iframe case is a good point. However, you'll want to use _self, not _blank. _blank will cause a new blank untitled tab to open. _top will trigger window.onbeforeunload to fire. If the top frame is observing window.onbeforeunload, you may see a warning like "Are you sure you want to leave this page?" (If you click yes, the mailto will still work fine.) See this plunker http://embed.plnkr.co/12QvXVVbSKjuVT1cjrc0/preview Note that plunker's preview window is in an iframe and if you click edit then run you'll see an onbeforeunload warning message for the _top example.

Comment: @kendsnyder Thanks for your advice. However in my case as I set up gmail (in Chrome) as my default email application, _self doesn't do anything when I clicked on the link.

Answer (score 6):

Here is the solution I ended up with:
Tested with Chrome, Firefox, IE6, IE7, IE8, IE9, IE10, IE11, Safari

```
$("a[href^='mailto:']").on("click",function() {
    window.top.location = $(this).prop("href");
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Strangely I couldn't get that to work - it seemed to die inside jquery somewhere (we're using V 1.6.1 still). But as soon as I used the click method instead it worked well. Good stuff.

Comment: Yes, on is the new click for newer versions of jQuery.

Answer (score 3):

This will also work, and won't close the window with Facebook.

```
<a href="mailto:..." target="_blank">...</a>
```

or

```
$("a[href^='mailto:']").attr('target','_blank');
```

Answer (score 3):

add target="_top" or "_blank" or "_parent"

`<a target="_top" href="mailto:a@b.c">email1</a>`

`<a target="_top" href="mailto:a@b.c">email2</a>`

Answer (score 1):

Possibly because your parent frameset is https, but Chrome now seems to treat the mailto link as insecure.

I just came across a similar issue when triggering a mailto link via

```
window.location = 'mailto:...'
```

Changing it to this worked around it.

```
window.open( 'mailto:...')
```

Comment: It sounds like its a bug then? In which case I should file a bug report?

Comment: OK, your workaround does open a new email, but it also opens a new, blank, tab/window which isn't desirable. I've opened a bug report with google.

Comment: Yup it does. We had to script it immediately closing, which is still a bit rubbish.

Answer (score 0):

This is my workaround until Chrome bug is fixed:

```
$.browser.chrome = /chrom(e|ium)/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()); 

if($.browser.chrome){
     myWindow=window.open("mailto:"+eml+"?subject="+msb,'','width=50,height=50');
     myWindow.close();
} else {
    window.location.href = "mailto:"+eml+"?subject="+msb;
}
```

For Chrome, make instance with window.open() method and close that instance immediately. Small window will "blink" for a short period but will do the job. It is "dirty" solution but as much as Chrome's bug.

For other browsers window.location() method can be used.