# mailto link is blocked as insecure content in Chrome Gmail

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, gmail, html-email, mailto

I've got a link in an encrypted HTML email that goes to mailto:blahblah, but it's being blocked in Chrome Gmail.  Anything I can do about this?

Example:

1) I open an **encrypted** HTML email message inside of my **encrypted** GMail web client (https://gmail.com - notice the **s** in https).

2) The email contains a link in the folloiwng format: `<a href="mailto:user@example.com">Email the user.</a>`

3) I click on the link, but it is blocked because GMail and/or Chrome is treating the mailto link as insecure content.

4) I add `target="_blank"` to the aforementioned link and the problem goes away.

The rest of the message displays and functions correctly because, again, both the message *and* my email client are using encryption.  The only thing that does not work is the mailto link.

Bonus question: how are mailto links classified with regard to protocols such as HTTP and HTTPS?  Links to a W3C document would be helpful.

Answer (score 10):

From here: [mailto link not working within a frame chrome (over https)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19234680/mailto-link-not-working-within-a-frame-chrome-over-https)

The suggestion is to use `target="_top"` instead of `target="_blank"`.

Comment: i have tried top and blank and yet "connection is not secure", if i remove the mailto from the action goes fully secure so def is the form, any help?  site is www.mr-programs.com

Comment: I found that I could use either value for target, but just needed the http, following this answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/56555013/8796340

Answer (score 3):

I solved this with a little JavaScript trick.

Here is my index.html

```
<div>
    <input id="cname" required="" name="subject" type="text">
    <label for="cname">Name</label>
    <textarea id="cmessage" required="" name="body"></textarea>
    <label class="label-control" for="cmessage">Your message</label>
</div>
<button onclick="sendMail()">Click me</button>
```

and script.js which get loaded into index.html earlier.

```
function sendMail() {    
    var body = document.getElementById("cmessage").value;
    var subject = document.getElementById("cname").value;

    window.location.replace(`mailto:hello@domain.com?body=${body}&subject=${subject} wants to contact you`);    
}
```

and now I got the full green lock back.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add `target="_blank"` to the mailto link.

Comment: The problem with this solution is an unnecessary blank tab is opened in Chrome before the parameters in the mailto link are passed off to the email client specified by the OS.

Answer (score 0):

I found simple solution for it just add https:// before your form action like:

```
<a href="mailto:user@example.com">Email the user.</a>
```

Change it to :

```
<a href="https://mailto:user@example.com">Email the user.</a>
```

I solved my issue by doing this I hope this work for you.
If you get the solution please mark as solution. 
Thank you.

Comment: this isn't working for me. did you set up a redirect for your link? and how?

Comment: This worked for me and other solutions did not.

Comment: @kenmistry Hey I believe its too late to answer. However, I have not added any redirection links.