# Chrome - You connection to this site is not fully secure

Tags: google-chrome, ssl

I've recently had an SSL installed onto my server.

I'm getting the "Your connection to this site is not fully secure" warning when using Chrome. I understand this relates to passive elements being loaded over a non secure connection and I understand what this means.

I cannot find any elements on the site being loaded over a non secure network and I've run it through a tool to check and not found any. I've created a blank HTML page with nothing on it and so I presume no chance of there being an element loaded on a non secure connection but I still get the warning.

Does anyone know why this may be?

Thanks

Comment: This was user error. There was a rewrite rule in the .htaccess file writing things back to http. My fault sorry for the question.

Comment: If you're using an SSL certificate you have to use HTTPS instead of HTTP inside your HTML document

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think you get that message when you use https, but Google Chrome cannot correctly verify your certificate chain. You might want to make sure you have followed the instructions on that end fully, and that all certificates are installed correctly.

If/when you have, this is how you can check that every request uses https:

- Open the website on Google Chrome
- Press F12
- Open the network tab
- Press f5 to reload everthing
- There it has all the information you should need. Hover over a request to check whether it uses http or https

Comment: You don't need to hover each URL. You can right click on table header and then enable 'Scheme' and it will show whether it is http or https.

Answer (score 23):

In addition to Daniël's answer, I also found a insecure future form submit can cause this warning.

My web page has below form

```
<form action="http://example.com/..."  >
    <input >... 
</form>
```

Changing the action's value from http to https fixed the warning.

Or change to a "relative" protocol.

```
<form action="//example.com/..."  >
```

Also, in Chrome, hit F12 to open developer tools, go to Console, there is the details of the warning

[image]

Comment: Thanks you saved my time

Comment: so i went and checket console for www.mr-programs.com indeed it was pointing to a form, my form is a mailto tho so i am quite uncertain what to change <form action="mailto:livingandwasting@hotmail.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain" class="mt-4 mt-md-0">

Comment: This can also happen with other static files that are being loaded using `http` connections, like fonts, images, stylesheets, JS, etc.

Comment: @Mr-Programs You may want to consider a form backend service such as formspree.io or formcarry.com as an alternative to the classic `mailto:`, which is inherently insecure.

Comment: I had images that were loaded prior to enabling SSL, and they were evidently using HTTP.  I deleted them, updated the website and re-uploaded them again.  This seemed to fix this issue.

Comment: In addition to the this I found my problem was also with mailto where this answer fixed it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56555013/547262