# Wordpress links all https but connection not fully secure

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome-devtools, insecure-connection

I've reconfigured a Wordpress site to use https and although there are no http links appearing in the html source Chrome still says "connection not fully secure".

I've read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46563293/chrome-you-connection-to-this-site-is-not-fully-secure) and I find in Developer Tools > Network there is a jpg file listed as being on an http connection. However I've changed the only reference to this file in the database in table wp_posts in field guid to be https, refreshed the browser cache but it is still listed as http although not appearing in the source.

Other non-wordpress https sites on the same server show the secure sign so the certificate must be installed correctly.

I've used the online checker at [www.whynopadlock.com](http://www.whynopadlock.com) and the only item it flags as a fail is the jpg image, which I've changed? Is there a WP cache, I can't see an cache plugins in admin.

Comment: Please read the first line of my question.

Comment: Share your site url

Comment: What I don't understand is why the jpg is referenced in Chrome developer tools network tab when it does not show in the page source.

Comment: FOUND IT in a stylesheet background url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to search for all http:// version of the website in your database but also, change the name of the website in the main settings to https AND flush your permalinks if you haven't in Settings -> permalinks  -> click update.

If it doesn't change anything, maybe the file is hard-coded in your template file? Another script could load the file via ajax you wouldn't see it in the source code...

Comment: Chrome dev tools network I notice it says the initiator for the jpg is analytics.js:44

Comment: Make sure you've included analytics via SSL.

Comment: It was an absolute path for background url in the stylesheet that caused the not fully secure issue.

Answer (score 0):

Test it in another Browser.

Maybe there is some Server-Cache (PHP, Memcached, etc.).

In bulk WP should have the change an affect.

Comment: Yes already tested in FF and now tested in whynopadlock.com. I'm not aware of any server cache. Sorry I don't understand the last line in your comment.

Comment: If you had changed the link inside the database and there is no caching-plugin, the link at frontend should be have changed also. Have you checked the link in backend?

Comment: Yes I have re-checked all tables in the database for instances of the image name with url and the only instance I found before changing was in wp_posts in field guid, for that entry the post_type is 'attachment'. Maybe the system is using a path setting to which it appends the image file name. I will re-search for the path domain (which is the old site domain) in the database.

Comment: But have you checkt it in the WP-backend, not the database way? Do you navigate to the site in BE with the attachment and reset the link there?

Comment: Sorry where are you suggesting I look? I've checked url settings in Settings>General and Settings>Permalinks, they are all https. I've now replaced all references to the old domain name in the database to the new domain, but still no change. In dev tools network I notice it says the initiator for the jpg is analytics.js:44

Comment: so check the analytics.js is pulled over https and the also reference inside the file. =)

Comment: It was an absolute path for background url in the stylesheet that caused the not fully secure issue.