# Loading unsecured elements - no https on whole site

Tags: wordpress, security, ssl, https, hosting

So I have SSL included with my hosting, but I noticed the site I setup a month or so ago does not appear as secure. I spoke with them as to why and they said it is because I am loading unsecured elements on the page, which makes the whole site appear as  not secure to the browsers.

It's just a Wordpress installation with a theme bought of Envato market. Unfortunately I don't understand what this means and they don't seem very eager to explain either, so I'm looking for some help. How do I go about fixing this? There are no payments or anything of the sort on the site, but getting "connection not secure" everytime you open it is not cool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check which protocol is used for all files loaded from remote.
If you get the "connection not secure" message you have to check all the loaded files for `http` and have to change it to `https`.

E.g.: `http://www.google.com/humans.txt` must be changed to `https://www.google.com/humans.txt`

You can check all loaded files per Google Chrome via Plugin like [HTTPS Mixed Content Locator](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/https-mixed-content-locat/pbljfomgollbampmcmalflifheichabj)

or by:

- Open the website on Google Chrome
- Press F12
- Open the network tab
- Press f5 to reload everthing
- There is has all the information you should need. Hover over a
  request to check whether it uses http or https

([copied from - here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46563412/8836495))

Comment: Indeed. Some of the internal images in loaded through http, which messed up the whole thing.

Comment: sometimes it is hidden in some CSS-files

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have updated .htaccess file in your site's main directory

```
# BEGIN WordPress
    
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

`# END WordPress</pre>`

I hope your site will now force all connections to be secure.

OR, You can install plugin called **Fix SSL/Non-SSL Links** that will force all image, CSS, and JS file requests inside the HTML page produced by Wordpress that matches the page request's HTTPS protocol.

Answer (score 1):

Kard, I too have a WordPress with a theme bought at Envato.

To switch my site to SSL I

i. Set the site url in Settings-General to https scheme.

ii. Defined redirect in htaccess

```
# SSL
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

This worked fine.