# ssl termination on ingress nginx digital ocean

Tags: docker, ssl, ssl-certificate, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

i am using ingress controller with cert-magaer on K8s.

my container running inside pod on port 80 and 443 and service running on 80,443.

installed tls certificate on ingress. but it giving error "Your Connection to this site is not fully secure"

this is my ingress

```
    apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: moodle-ingress
  annotations:  
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    certmanager.k8s.io/cluster-issuer: moodle-prod
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/secure-backends: "true"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - domain
    secretName: moodle-prod
  rules:
  - host: domain
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: moodle
          servicePort: 443
```

Comment: Check for the "Mixed Content" as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46563293/chrome-you-connection-to-this-site-is-not-fully-secure).

Comment: @mk_sta it was mix content problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current error reflects a problem with "Mixed content" as I admitted in the comment, thus most probably some web page contains both secure (HTTPS) and non-secure (HTTP) content elements delivered to the web browser as well. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46563293/chrome-you-connection-to-this-site-is-not-fully-secure) is the link to the similar issue reported on Stack community.