# mailto href inside frame not working when Content Security Policy

Tags: iframe, href, mailto, content-security-policy

**Summary**:

Site at `https://localhost:3000` , with `Content-Security-Policy` value of `default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://localhost:3001/https_index.html` contains iframe pointing at `https://localhost:3001/index.html`. The contents of `:3001/index.html` contain an `<a href="mailto..."></a>`. Clicking that link fails: `Refused to frame '' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive...`. **How can I change my CSP value to prevent this error; to open an new email in user's preferred email client (normal behavior of `mailto`)?** I am using Chrome<sup>1</sup>

**Detail**:

Similar but different than [this question "mailto link not working within a frame chrome (over https)
"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19234680/1175496)

I think mine is not a duplicate because:

1. I *cannot* reproduce that bug, I see a console **warning** about [mixed-content](https://googlesamples.github.io/web-fundamentals/fundamentals/security/prevent-mixed-content/passive-mixed-content.html) when I try to reproduce their steps:

   > Mixed Content: The page at 'https://localhost:3001/https_index.html' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'mailto:...'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.
2. My steps are specific; both my page & its iframe src are `https`, but the page itself is served with a specific and *restrictive* `Content-Security-Policy` (`CSP`):

   `app.use(csp({
     directives: {
       defaultSrc: ["'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://localhost:3001/https_index.html"]
       }
     }));`
3. Also the resulting **error** I *can* reproduce is different:

   > Refused to frame '' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' https://localhost:3001/https_index.html". Note that 'frame-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

With an image like:
[image: showing Google Chrome sad-face icon suggesting error; the message says 'Requests to the server have been blocked by an extension']

4. The [accepted answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23224692/1175496)  for the original questions *will* help me work around *my CSP*-specific issue, that is, if I add a `target="_top"` to the link, the email client opens without error: 
   `<a target="_top" href="mailto:...">email</a>`
   A similar fix works for another [similar but different issue.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23555592/1175496) However, this *may*<sup>1</sup> sometimes open a new tab

So my question is specifically about the [`Content-Security-Policy` error (see above)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30280370/1175496):

> ...Refused to frame '' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: ...

Notice it says `frame ''`. The frame is identified as an **empty string**!

Normally if some resource violates CSP, [the URL of the resource is identified; i.e.](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/csp/images/csp-error.png)

> Refused to laod the script 'http://evil.com/evil.js'...

And if the `CSP`-violating URL is identified + provided I can use it; add it to my `CSP` value for `default-src`:

```
`app.use(csp({
  directives: {
    defaultSrc: ["http://evil.com/evil.js 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://localhost:3001/https_index.html"]
    }
  }));`
```

But can I allow an exception for an `href` value? Specifically for `mailto`? I tried wildcards like `mailto*`, but:

> The source list for Content Security Policy directive 'default-src' contains an invalid source: 'mailto*'.

And I wonder if any wildcard would work anyway; does Chrome really consider the `href="mailto..."` frame as an empty string? I suppose so, since it's not a URL per se; Chrome "wants" to launch an external application (i.e. Outlook) in the context of the iframe; who is bound to the CSP rules of its parent page...

**Footnotes:**

1. Chrome displays the above errors in CSP or sandbox cases. Internet Explorer doesn't complain about an `iframes` href, despite the value of `CSP`. Internet Explorer also doesn't have the "new tab" problem, despite the value of `sandbox`. IE 11.1914 will just give message:

[image: Internet Explorer dialog asking user to confirm they want to allow this page to open Outlook to a source of href, and choose to ignore this message in future]

2. The fix of using `target="_top"` *may open a new tab* , if you've `sandbox`ed your iframe! (`sandbox` is different than `CSP`). I don't like the new tab. Chrome gave me this error...

   > Unsafe JavaScript attempt to initiate navigation for frame with URL 'http://localhost:3000/' from frame with URL 'https://localhost:3001/index.html'. The frame attempting navigation of the top-level window is sandboxed, but the flag of 'allow-top-navigation' or 'allow-top-navigation-by-user-activation' is not set.

... but opened a new tab, as well as the Outlook email client...

[image: showing a new tab opened in Chrome browser, whose URL is set to the "mailto:" value from within the iframe]

I did what the error suggested; modifying the value of the `iframe` `sandbox` attribute:
`sandbox="allow-top-navigation allow-same-origin ..."`, and the mailto link worked (as before), but did *not* open an excessive new tab. Great!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Stumbled upon this question after encountering the same issue. There is surprisingly little documentation about this after hours of searching.

My first instinct was to do something like you were doing, `mailto*` or `mailto:*`.

What finally ended up working was omitting the wildcards, and altering the `frame-src` directive as such:

`frame-src 'self' mailto: tel: *.mydomain.com`

`tel:` links were also were broken in iframes.

Comment: this is exactly what I needed, thanks for sharing Mark

Comment: In my case frame-src returns error for other reason, so I added it to "child-src mailto: tel: *.mydomain.com" and it works too.