# Mailto doesn't work in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, mailto

For some reason mailto works in every browser but chrome for me. is it just me or is it not supported anymore? because it had worked for me before
 but now it doesn't. not even the [W3 schools mailto example](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_mail) works but it does try to but for some reason it doesn't work [as seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNysU.png).
It's not just my computer I've also  tried a different computer in my house and I have also made sure that no chrome extensions are interrupting it.

Update: here is an example of mailto code that doesn't work for me:

```html
<form action="MAILTO:someone@example.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
Name:<br>
<input type="text" name="name" value="your name"><br>
E-mail:<br>
<input type="text" name="mail" value="your email"><br>
Comment:<br>
<input type="text" name="comment" value="your comment" size="50"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Send">
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
```

Comment: can you show us the code thats not working for you please - it's working here.

Comment: Did you verify your settings handlers on Chrome?
Open this address with Chrome and verify chrome://settings/handlers

Comment: yes @DomenicoVacchiano I opened the link and there was not any active protocol handlers and it allowed sites to ask to become default handlers.

Comment: Chrome Version 47.0.2526.106 (64-bit), OSX El Capitan it works fine for me.

Comment: It appears to be user specific and has already been resolved [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17517600/mailto-links-do-nothing-in-chrome-but-work-in-firefox)