# How to ask permision so others can open mailto

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to open mail on click in js. I'm using mailto, but in chrome you need to change the handlers settings to make it work.

My question is can I make some sort of popup that ask for persmission and changes this setting to others?

PS: to give permision for me I only found this way:

1. Open Gmail in Chrome and click the Protocol Handler icon overlapping-diamonds in your browser's address bar.
2. When prompted to "Allow Gmail to open all email links?", select "Use Gmail," and click "Done."

**EDIT**

My code to send the mail

```
$("#applyText").click(function(){    
    var email = 'mail@gmail.com';
    var subject = 'Hire me im a genius';
    var emailBody = 'Hi Sample,';
    document.location = "mailto:"+email+"? 
    subject="+subject+"&body="+emailBody;
});
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: `$("#applyText").click(function(){ if (confirm("May I send this to you in an email? If yes, please allow this if prompted") { ............. } );`

Comment: So this prompt is only visible when gmail is default `mailto:` handler? What about other mailing tools?

Comment: yes the mail only opens when you change this hadler setting. I only found mailto so far

Answer (score 0):

> this is browser settings specific, ie. it will behave differently depending on the user's browser settings. The user can change how `mailto:` links behave in chrome by visiting `chrome://settings/handlers`, or `Chrome Settings->Content Settings->Manage Handlers...`

This is an answer to that [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17517600/mailto-links-do-nothing-in-chrome-but-work-in-firefox/17635636#17635636).

**So to answer your question**
No it is not possible because this is browser settings.

But most browsers should open it without a problem. For me this works properly.

By the way, you have some minor mistakes in your code.

**Here is an working example**

```js
$("#applyText").click(function() {
  var email = 'mail@gmail.com';
  var subject = 'Hire me im a genius';
  var emailBody = 'Hi Sample,';
  document.location = "mailto:" + email + "?subject=" + subject + "&body=" + emailBody;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="applyText">Click</button>
```