# Hyperlink to email address

Tags: html, email, web

I'm trying to create a clickable email address which when clicked on, opens up the visitors' email application with the email address in the "send to".

I tried using:

```
<a href="mailto:emailaddress@whatever.com">mailto:emailaddress@whatever.com</a>
```

It works well when the link is displayed on a mobile. It opens up the Gmail application. However, when I try to click on it on the web it does nothing.

Thank you!

Comment: See this answer, maybe can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17517600/mailto-links-do-nothing-in-chrome-but-work-in-firefox

Answer (score 5):

Your link is valid.

`mailto` links are signal for your browser to open a default e-mail application.

Try specifying default E-Mail application in your OS or another browser.

P.S. `<a href="mailto:emailaddress@whatever.com">Email Us</a>` also works well

Answer (score 2):

That is possible, if your visitor has a default mail app on their computer. Same way as they have gmail/iosmail/anymailapp on their phone.