# Send email using the installed mail client in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, google-chrome, email, email-client

How can I send an email without attachments using the default email client installed on Windows 10/8/7? I tried the following code, but it just opens a blank page in the Chrome browser.

```
    var url = "mailto:someone@somewhere.com?subject=Test&body=Hello";
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(url);
```

I can fix the problem by changing the default mail client from Google Chrome to MS Outlook, but shouldn't Google Chrome automatically open Gmail in this case?

Answer (score 2):

try this answer [Mailto links do nothing in Chrome but work in Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17517600/mailto-links-do-nothing-in-chrome-but-work-in-firefox)

```
 var url = "mailto:someone@somewhere.com?subject=Test&body=Hello";
 System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"path\chrome.exe",url);
```

[Google Chrome open Gmail result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvZtk.png)