# New tab when clicking on mailto link

Tags: html, mailto

I made a mailto link that should take the user to their chosen email host, however, when I click on it, I get a new tab opened in chrome. If I try it with another browser, it opens a window on chrome as well. How could I fix this?

```
<div class="contact-icons container-fluid row justify-content-md-center">
            <div class="col-md-1 icon">
                <a href="https://www.instagram.com/federicazosi" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-3x"></i></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-5 icon">
                <a href="mailto:zosifederica@gmail.com" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa-3x"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: You were re-directed to a new tab because of the `target="_blank"` attribute you added to your anchor tag "<a>"

Comment: @DavidNgumbu, thank you for you answer. In Chrome, If i remove `target="_blank"` nothing happens when I click on the link. If I try it from Internet Explorer, it still redirects me to Google Chrome.

Comment: @DavidNgumbu, never mind. It worked for Chrome, but for Internet Explorer, it still redirects me to Google Chrome's main page.

Comment: For more info about the `mailto` attribute I reccommend this post I found on stack overflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17517600/mailto-links-do-nothing-in-chrome-but-work-in-firefox).